# Invalid Scope error while retrieving an Authentication token for creating a skype bot

Tags: rest, skype-for-business

As per the article below, I am trying to retrieve a token for creating a Skype bot.

Article:

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication#authentication-technologies

Command used:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-d 'client_id=<your-app-id>&client_secret=<your-app-secret>&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default' 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": 
       "AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input 
        parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default is not valid.\r\n
        Trace ID: 43082e14-9e0b-4a2c-a532-47d0a55a50a4\r\n
        Correlation ID: 6c79b873-9e28-4842-8803-15e4c25af1e3\r\n
        Timestamp: 2016-09-06 05:27:16Z",       
  "error_codes": [
     70011
  ],
  "timestamp": "2016-09-06 05:27:16Z",
  "trace_id": "43082e14-9e0b-4a2c-a532-47d0a55a50a5",
  "correlation_id": "6c79b873-9e28-4842-8803-15e4c25af1e6"
}
```

Comment: did you figure out what was the problem ?